# Snowflake : Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Tags: numbers, boolean, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowflake as a data warehouse.  I have a CSV file at AWS S3. I am writing a merge sql to merge data received in CSV to the table in snowflake. I have a column in time dimension table with data type as Number(38,0) data type in SF. This table holds all dates time, one e.g. is of column 
time_id= 232 and time=12:00
In CSV I am getting a column with the label as time and value as 12:00.

In merge sql I am fetching this value and trying to get time_id for it.

```
update table_name set start_time_dim_id = (select time_id from time_dim t where t.time_name = csv_data.start_time_dim_id)
```

On this statement I am getting this error "SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated"

I am struggling to solve it, during this I google for it and got one reference for it 
https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/251
So want to make sure if anyone have encountered this issue? If yes, will appreciate pointers over it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61604487/unsupported-subquery-type-cannot-be-evaluated)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a conversion issue. I suggest you to check the data in CSV file. Maybe there is a wrong or missing value. Please check your data, and make sure it returns numeric values

```
create table simpleone ( id number );
insert into simpleone values ( True );
```

The last statement fails with:

```
SQL compilation error: Expression type does not match column data type, expecting NUMBER(38,0) but got BOOLEAN for column ID
```

If you provide sample data, and SQL to produce this error, maybe we can provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply  yes it is resolved now I am getting Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated. I have a merge sql and while setting value of column I have to get its values from another table using subquery .

Comment: Maybe you can provide the full query (and the exact error message) so we can see which subquery is failing.

Comment: Inner query is giving problem.  MERGE INTO evaluation_fact eval_fact using ( SELECT $27 tim_id , $28 dt_id , $13 w_id FROM @REPORTING_MERGE_STAGE/reporting-data-ingest/Evaluation-IT.csv) csv_data ON eval_fact.w_id = csv_data.w_id WHEN matched THEN UPDATE SET tim_id= (select day_id from dates_dim d where d.day_id=csv_data.tim_id) , dt_id= (select time_id from time_dim t where t.time_name=csv_data.dt_id) WHEN NOT matched THEN INSERT ( tim_id, dt_id ) VALUES ( (select day_id from dates_dim d where d.day_id=csv_data.tim_id) , (select time_id from time_dim t where t.time_name=csv_data.dt_id) );.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately correlated and nested subqueries in Snowflake are a bit limited at this stage.

I would try running something like this:

```
update table_name 
set start_time_dim_id= time_id 
from time_dim
where t.time_name=csv_data.start_time_dim_id
```